# How to set root directory to fix 404 POST in javascript for Axios + Vue Component + Laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, vue.js, axios

I'm following a tutorial to learn Vue+Laravel and it uses Axios for the Ajax request on these lines in the script for the Vue Component.  The error causing me grief is on the console log is:

```
    POST http://localhost/favorite/2 404 (Not Found)
```

my website lives locally on wamp at a different folder which looks like the issue.  I can't use the normal laravel "Url(' ') helper function to get the route directory.  So how would I do this in javascript rather just hardcoding my local host site in which isn't good for pushing to a real server in the future.  Thanks!

http://localhost/laravel/public/

```
        methods: {
        favorite(post) {
            axios.post('/favorite/'+post)
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = true)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        },

        unFavorite(post) {
            axios.post('/unfavorite/'+post)
                .then(response => this.isFavorited = false)
                .catch(response => console.log(response.data));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Use a constant in your JS to set an api base url, then you can just concat the constant in your axios calls. You then only need to change it in one place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a new axios instance when the component is mounted:

```
mounted() {
    this.axios = axios.create({
        baseURL: 'http://localhost',
    });
}
```

You could even go ahead an store the base uri in a data attribute:

```
data() {
    baseUri: 'http://localhost',
},

mounted() {
    this.axios = axios.create({
        baseURL: this.baseUri,
    });
}
```

Then later in your methods you can make use of `this.axios`. See [the docs](https://github.com/axios/axios#axioscreateconfig) for reference.

Cheers!